# Regex Or split based on number

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, srt

i have trouble splitting a vtt file which is chunked together as one string.

i have this string: "3 00:00:09.023 --> 00:00:11.953 Only by looking at her sitting with her legs spread widely, 4 00:00:11.953 --> 00:00:13.593 you can tell she's a troublemaker."

I want to make it like this

**3**

00:00:09.023 --> 00:00:11.953

Only by looking at her sitting with her legs 
spread widely,

**4**

00:00:11.953 --> 00:00:13.593

you can tell she's a troublemaker.

with every number(3,4...etc) as the new line. i several thousand numbers to split

appreciate if any 1 could help! 
thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe: [`str = str.replace(/\d+ \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d{3} --> \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d{3}/g, '\n$&')`](https://regex101.com/r/NWXZT3/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string structure is fixed, you may use this:

```
var yourString = "3 00:00:09.023 --> 00:00:11.953 Only by looking at her sitting with her legs spread widely, 4 00:00:11.953 --> 00:00:13.593 you can tell she's a troublemaker.";
var newString = yourString.replace(/\d+\s\d{2}/g,'\n$&');
```

if this code does not cover all the cases, you should give more details.

Comment: HI, could you check the question again.. its is possible to format it to another way?

Comment: @GuangJunSotong i think it'll be better if you put the code that you tried

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookahead to match a number and space character that is followed by the first time (00:00:09.023) and replace that by a newline character (`\n`) and the matched digit.

```
var subtitleLines = str.replace(/(\d+\s(?=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}))/)/g, "\n$1")
```

To be more secure, in case some of the strings happen to include the now matched substring, you can include more of the time portion, e.g.

```
/(\d+\s(?=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}\s-->))/
```